# Flume plugin sources from RabbitMQ Queue and Sink to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, rabbitmq, flume-ng

Is there any flume plugin, Which sources from RabbitMQ Queue and Sink to Cassandra.

```
RabbitMQ <== Flume Source ==> Sink ==> Cassandra.
```

Or any other way to consume RabbitMQ Queue and store in Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

For RabbitMQ sources, you can try [this one](https://github.com/aweber/rabbitmq-flume-plugin) or [this one](https://github.com/stampy88/flume-amqp-plugin).

For Cassandra sinks: you can try [this one](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-flume-sink-and-logsandra-integration) or [this one](https://github.com/btoddb/flume-ng-cassandra-sink), but they are pretty old; you can also have a look at [Stratio Ingestion](https://github.com/Stratio/Ingestion): it's a fork of Flume, and they have a [Cassandra sink](https://github.com/Stratio/Ingestion/tree/master/stratio-sinks/stratio-cassandra-sink).

Comment: Thanks..!!  Can i achieve from above links that  Flume-Source will consume messages from RabbitMQ Queue and Flume-Sink will insert in Cassandra Table.